# Dependency injection with Dagger during Gson deserialization

Tags: java, dependency-injection, gson, dagger

In my application, I have objects created not by me, but by a Gson deserializer. These objects need references to singleton instances that everywhere else I am able to provide using constructor injection.

However, accessing the related component within the default constructor called by Gson like this

```
DaggerExampleComponent.builder().build().inject(this)
```

will not reuse the singletons injected everywhere else - from what I understood, this is because the builder will in fact create a new instance of `ExampleComponent` that does not know anything about the existing one.

My workaround is to keep a static `instance` field within `ExampleComponent` along with a getter, but I would like to know if there is a best practice of how to achieve the same thing with another approach.

**EDIT** The deserialization is being done on data retrieved from a database using the [Android Room Persistence library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room). Converting data to custom objects is being implemented by using the `@TypeConverter` annotation on static methods, which are called implicitly when an element is retrieved from the database. This prevents me from injecting the created objects right there - the converters are static methods within a static class that is not instantiated, so I can not pass the DaggerComponent object to it to be used for injecting created instances, as suggested by Thorben below.

Comment: Are you storing the DaggerAppComponent, which is the result of the ".build()" method? It appears, that you will always use a new AppComponent, which will always create a new instance of your singleton

Comment: That's what I was talking about - currently I can only see a way out by keeping the DaggerAppComponent accessible from everywhere, which feels kinda wrong.. I mean what's the point in using dagger then. I could as well just keep all other instances accessible from a central location as well.

Comment: Are you using a custom JsonDeserializer/JsonSerializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Disclaimer

I have not worked with Dagger in a long time. Take the following solutions with a grain of salt! The solution worked for me locally.

### Without DaggerExampleComponent

One answer to you problem might be, to use a custom [JsonDeserializer](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html) interface implementation, which takes the instance of the object you want to inject as an constructor argument.

You could write your own deserializer, that injects the singleton instance into the deserialized Object like this:

```
class MyJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<MyObject> {

    private final MyComponent singleton;

    public MyJsonDeserializer(MyComponent component) {
        this.singleton = component;
    }

    public MyObject deserialize(JsonElement json, Type tye, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        // you could here parse some arguments
        return new MyObject(singleton);
    }
}
```

You would register it like this:

```
MyComponent component = ...
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(MyObject.class, new MyJsonDeserializer(component)).create();
```

If you would have the MyComponent class be injected, you would ensure, that every created object has the same instance of the MyComponent object.

I personally would prefer this solution, to not mix up Dagger and Gson.

### Using Dagger

You could as well change the code to use the DaggerAppComponent in said JsonDeserializer like this:

```
class MyJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<MyObject> {

    private final DaggerAppComponent singletonProvider;

    public MyJsonDeserializer(DaggerAppComponent componentProvdider) {
        this.singletonProvider = componentProvider;
    }

    public MyObject deserialize(JsonElement json, Type tye, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        // you could here parse some arguments
        MyObject object =  ...
        singletonProvider.inject(object);
        return object;
    }
}
```

and change the registration like this:

```
DaggerAppComponent componentBuilder = DaggerExampleComponent.builder().build();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(MyObject.class, new MyJsonDeserializer(componentBuilder)).create();
```

---

**UPDATE**

Because of the new information, i would suggest to enhance the existing class, that is used for the Android Room Persistence library (the class that contains the annotated method) like this:

```
class Convert {
    static DaggerAppComponent singletonProvider;
    @TypeConverter
    public static MyObject convert(String arg) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(MyObject.class, new MyJsonDeserializer(componentBuilder)).create();
        return gson.fromJson(arg, MyObject.class);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromArrayLisr(MyObject object) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(v);
        return json;
    }
}
```

I took some inspiration from [thetechguru](https://thetechguru.in/storing-java-objects-primitive-types-room-database/). Also, this asumes the same JsonDeserializer that is stated above.

Since i do not know the acutal parameters, i asume String as the argument to this typeconverter. Insert you corresponding type there.

To use this effectivly, somewhere in the code (before any database related stuff is done), this should be called:

```
Convert.singletonProvider = DaggerExampleComponent.builder().build();
```

This will allow the Convert class to see the correct DaggerAppComponent.

There might still be an issue with this. This is a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), concering the null state of the static variable. If the database is called to soon, the result will be a NullpointerException, since the static field has not been set yet. To counteract this, you could use a Semaphore (or anything semilliar), to create some sort of barrier. With a Semaphore, this would include a simple Semaphore that has 0 permits. Before using the variable calling acquire and release on it. After the variable has been set (outside of this class), calling release on it once.

This is not a good solution (in terms of software design), but it should do the trick.

Comment: Hmm the Gson deserialization is done from within a `TypeConverter` class for the Android Room Persistence library, which I can't control either (meaning I can't pass the `Component` instance to it because I am not instantiating it)...

Comment: 1) So you are not providing the TypeConverter instance?

Comment: 2) Could you alter you question, to include this (and more) detail(s)?

Comment: @DavidSchneider I edited the original post. If there is anything not quite right about it (because your code cannot support it), could you post some more code?

Comment: Thanks! This brings me back to the Component origin part of my question - whether to _set_ the deserializer's `component` instance externally, or provide a static `getInstance()` within the Component to enable centralized management. You're doing the former here, is that for a particular reason? Do you consider it better practice or do you maybe even see practical advantages in this approach?

Comment: **EDIT** Last remark was silly, since the DaggerComponent class is generated. Adding my own `getInstance()` is not possible.